# Getting at data from a join table in rails with known information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

EDIT: This was answered but I really meant to ask a more complex question...didn't want to open a new one the answer helped but it wasn't a full answer for what I am trying to do... more edits after code.

I have a join table that joins two models:
A group
and a Location (which is actually an address id from the address table).  This join table is called Group_Locations

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
    belongs_to :designation
    belongs_to :specialty
    has_many :provider_locations
    has_many :invoices
    has_many :groups, through: :provider_locations

end

class ProviderLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider
  belongs_to :group_location

end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base


    #validations
    validates :group_name, presence: true

    #associations
    has_many :providers 
    has_many :invoices
    has_one  :billing

    has_many :group_locations
end
```

That is great my other model is:

```
class GroupLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :provider_locations

end
```

and Address:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_locations
    has_many :billings
end
```

So with all these associations I can write a nice test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class GroupLocationTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

   test "adding a group and an address" do
    group = Group.new
    group.group_name = 'MyGroup'
    group.save

    adr = Address.new
    adr.city = 'Las Cruces'
    adr.state = 'New Mexico'
    adr.zip = '88012'
    adr.address_line_one = '382 Dark side of moon'
    adr.address_line_two = ''
    adr.save    

    gl  = GroupLocation.new
    gl.group = group
    gl.address=adr      
    assert gl.save, 'Group location did not save'
    puts gl.group.group_name
  end
end
```

EDIT::::  Thanks Daiku helped, but I have two other models (Provider and ProviderLocation) that now I want to the addresses and group names given the name of a provider.

Their relationship is a join table called ProviderLocation that has a group_location id and a provider_id in it.  So I am not sure t he associations (another through I am sure) I need to get to it... I had in my Provider model:

`has_many :groups, through: :group_locations`

This didn't work gave me an error when trying to use:

```
puts Provider.where(first_name: "Shane").first.groups.first.group_name
```

> ```
> 1) Error:
> ProviderLocationTest#test_adding_a_provider_to_a_group_location:
> NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
>     test/models/provider_location_test.rb:37:in `block in <class:ProviderLocationTest>'
> ```

Comment: a style comment: Speaking as one of the many folks who have come to clean up legacy code. It's in everyone's best interest to have names that don't mislead. `GroupLocation` implies a connection between Groups and Locations, but there aren't locations there are Address(es). Please don't make folks wonder where Location is or why it isn't called GroupAddress. Life will be better for everyone involved. :)

Comment: Your new associations are incomplete.  You have Provider that has_many groups through provider_locations, but your Group has_many providers, needs to be through provider_locations again.  I recommend you start a new question, rather than morph this one.  Especially if someone gave you a correct answer to your original question :-)

Comment: thanks guys I will do the new question, or if that would fix it I can update the associations.  and @masukomi, you are right.  That is a great idea.  I was to verbose on my names.

Comment: and done :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260679/dealing-with-associations-in-rails-for-has-many-through-but-two-models-deep

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to tell us you've "EDIT"ed something. We can see the changes if we need to. Instead, add the information where it makes sense in the document. Think of Stack Overflow as a cookbook of solutions to programming problems, similar to Wikipedia or an encyclopedia, or an informal reference book. Once a question is answered it's answered, and we don't edit/extend the question to ask more questions. Doing that dilutes the previous answers and confuses those who are search for answers to the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Group model, add an association:

`has_many :addresses, through: :group_locations`

Then you can:

`Group.where(group_name: "MyGroup").first.addresses.first`

Comment: This worked but I have edited the question above for a more complex case I thought I could now figure out but still had no luck...