# Dealing with associations in rails for has_many through...but two join tables deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Edit 4.  Something in my explanation is just not going right... attached is a (very poorly done graphic) that shows the tables and how the schema is, and then my main question is given what I have that a provider is joined via a group location id via the provider_location table, which the group location holds the group and ultimately the group name.   This is what I want to know, building a table like this how do I get to the group name? all the way from a provider.  It is like I need a has_many through through.  (BIG NOTE:  Provider Address and Group Address in the image is really Provider Location and Group Location)

[image: rough model diagram. a provider can have many addresses to many group locations. Generally a group has many addresses]

EDIT x 3:  Thanks @mrshoco.  It got me closer, now its like something else with my structure is not quite right.... I get this error when running provider_test_location.rb

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/ipanmv2$ rake test test/models/provider_location_tes
t.rb
Run options: --seed 18117

# Running:

E

Finished in 0.190900s, 5.2383 runs/s, 5.2383 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
ProviderLocationTest#test_fetching_a_group_name_for_a_provider:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: provider_
locations.group_id: SELECT groups.group_name FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "provider_
locations" ON "provider_locations"."group_id" = "groups"."id" INNER JOIN "provid
ers" ON "providers"."id" = "provider_locations"."provider_id" WHERE "providers".
"first_name" = 'Shane'
    test/models/provider_location_test.rb:37:in `puts'
    test/models/provider_location_test.rb:37:in `puts'
    test/models/provider_location_test.rb:37:in `block in <class:ProviderLocatio
nTest>'

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Here is the complete unit test

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProviderLocationTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

   test "adding a provider to a group location" do
    group = Group.new
    group.group_name = 'My Awesome'
    group.save
    adr = Address.new
    adr.city = 'Las Cruces'
    adr.state = 'New Mexico'
    adr.zip = '88012'
    adr.address_line_one = '382 Dark side of moon'
    adr.address_line_two = ''
    adr.save    

    gl  = GroupLocation.new
    gl.group = group
    gl.address=adr      
    gl.save


    prv = Provider.new
    prv.first_name = 'Shane'
    prv.last_name = 'Thomas'
    prv.save

    pl = ProviderLocation.new      
    pl.provider = prv
    pl.group_location = gl   ###############ISSUE

    assert pl.save, 'Provider location did not save'

    puts Group.joins(:providers).where(providers: { first_name: 'Shane' }).select('groups.group_name')




  end
end
```

The models are following:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :designation
    belongs_to :specialty
    has_many :provider_locations
    has_many :invoices
    has_many :groups, through: :provider_locations
end

class ProviderLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider
  belongs_to :group_location
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

    #validations
    validates :group_name, presence: true


    #associations
    has_many :providers, through: :provider_locations
    has_many :invoices
    has_one  :billing
    has_many :addresses, through: :group_locations


    has_many :group_locations
    belongs_to  :billing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'billing_address_id'
    belongs_to  :mailing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'mailing_address_id'
    has_and_belongs_to_many :insurances
    has_many :provider_locations



end


class GroupLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :group

end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_locations
    has_many :billings
end
```

Comment: I hope I understood your correctly. Below is my answer on your question. If something is still missing, please give more info. I really interested to collaborate on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a project which illustrates solution of your problem and it works. You can find it here https://github.com/dimakura/stackoverflow-projects/tree/master/32260679-dealing-with-associations. Below is description of the same concepts, so browsing the repository is completely optional.

Actually there are two ways to solve your problem both of them are usable in appropriate context.

But let's first create tables and models.

### Create tables

I simplified your tables, omitting irrelevant details. Below are scripts for creating them.

**groups** table:

```
create_table :groups do |t|
  t.string :group_name

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

**addresses** table:

```
create_table :addresses do |t|
  t.string :city
  t.string :state
  t.string :zip
  t.string :address_line_one
  t.string :address_line_two

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

**group_locations** table:

```
create_table :group_locations do |t|
  t.references :group, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.references :address, index: true, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

**providers** table:

```
create_table :providers do |t|
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

**provider_locations** table:

```
create_table :provider_locations do |t|
  t.references :provider, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.references :group_location, index: true, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

### Models

Below are relations between `Address`, `Group` and `GroupLocation` models:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_locations
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_locations
end

class GroupLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :address
  has_many :provider_locations
end
```

`ProviderLocation` is also simple:

```
class ProviderLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider
  belongs_to :group_location
end
```

Relatively complicated one is `Provider`:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :provider_locations
  has_many :group_locations, through: :provider_locations
  has_many :groups, through: :group_locations
end
```

You can see now, that from a given `Provider` you can easily navigate down to `Group`s.

Let's now test our setup.

### Testing

We have definition of your problem in this request:

> ... how to get all the groups a provider might belong to through the provider locations through group locations...

As I said in the begining there are two ways to solve your problem, depending on what's given.

Let's first assume we have a provider selected and want all groups related to this single provider.

```
class ProviderLocationTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    group = Group.create(group_name: 'My Awesome')
    adr = Address.create(city: 'Las Cruces', state: 'New Mexico', zip: '88012', address_line_one: '382 Dark Side of the Moon', address_line_two: '')
    gl =GroupLocation.create(group: group, address: adr)
    @provider = Provider.create(first_name: 'Shane', last_name: 'Thomas')
    pl = ProviderLocation.create(provider: @provider, group_location: gl)
  end

  test 'getting groups for a single provider' do
    assert_equal ['My Awesome'], @provider.groups.map{ |group| group.group_name }
  end
end
```

It's a great way when working with a single provider.

But there is another scenario, when we want to select all groups belonging to more than one provider. Even worse, we might be given request: "Give us all groups for providers whose age not exceeds 50".

In this case we can exploit direct joining.

Below we illustrate, how to use joining when we want to get groups for all providers whose first name is Shane.

```
test 'getting groups based on arbitrary query' do
  group_names = Group.joins(group_locations: [ provider_locations: :provider]).where("providers.first_name=?", 'Shane').map{ |group| group.group_name }
  assert_equal ['My Awesome'], group_names
end
```

Comment: This worked! I had one more comment... I keep editing ill just post new :)

Comment: I guess with this working my next thing is how to get the data the other way.  I had a setup in group_test similar to the def setup here with the @group there global and I tried:   @ group.providers.first.first_name   Didn't know what providers was...

Comment: You need to add some associations to Group to get providers easily. Do you want help on this too?

Comment: I think I got it!  Man you rock using what you did in providers I applied it to groups and got the associations here added:   has_many :provider_locations, through: :group_locations and I had this already  has_many :providers, through: :provider_locations
 Seems to work!

Answer (score 2):

```
# Group name given a provider name
Group.joins(:providers).where('providers.first_name' => 'Shane').select('groups.name')

# address/location of the provider given the group name
Provider.joins(:groups).where("groups.name" => "your_group_name").first.provider_locations.first
```

Comment: Gives me an error ' no such table groups_providers'

Comment: did you run your migration before? do you have groups_providers table?
Because, my query will join groups and providers tables only.

Comment: No if i change the association I didnt think I had to run a migration.  And No I do not have a groups providers table, that is it, they are joined via two other join tables:  Provider_Locations and Group_Locations

Comment: It's very weird. I am joining providers and groups table, then why is it complaining about groups_providers table?!?
Please post the error stack trace. I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer is correct

```
Group.joins(:providers).where(providers: { first_name: 'Shane' }).select('groups.name')
```

But you have an error 'no such table groups_providers' because in Provider model there is `has_and_belongs_to_many :groups` so rails are searching for providers_groups or groups_providers model. Instead of that you should write `has_many :groups, through: :provider_locations` and `belongs_to :group` in ProviderLocation model

Comment: That did change things, added an edit to the post describing what happened.

Comment: You don't need to delete `belongs_to :group_location`.
And you should change `has_many :groups, through: :group_locations` to `belongs_to :group` as i suggested before.

Comment: thanks again.  I did all the edits, was getting that no providers_groups table error and realized in my Group model I had a has and belongs to many, I took that out so now above is an edit with the error I get that makes no sense to me.  All models are updated to what they are now.

Comment: I should add that the klass error in my edit above makes no sense to me, is klass a thing? Looked like I had made a typo but that is what its called. *Shrug*

Comment: thanks mrshoco.  I am closer and learning a lot about associations , some how the join cannot find the id (added the error to the posted)

Comment: I think you just don't have group_id column in ProviderLocation model. Do
`rails g migration add_column_to_provider_location group_id:integer:index` and
`rake db:migrate`

Comment: Ahhh this is the case, my using of this must be wrong.  Because the provider_location has a provider_id and a group_location_id.  It is because the provider has a group though the location of the group...no idea what the true association like this is called..no idea how to get the data on it also.  It is done like this because a provider belongs to a group but to a group at a specific location.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to understand, the way i see it you have 5 tables, three which represent models:

- Provider
- Group
- Address

And another two that are join-tables:

- Provider-location
- Group-location

If I understand correctly, You have this because a group has many addresses and so does a provider. Also a provider has a relationship with group directly because it is not affected by the addresses, what i think you are missing is a the join table for groups_providers, this of course would need a migration to create said table. in which case you would have something of sort:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

If however. the relationship between provider and group is dependent on the address only, the relationship between provider and groups passes through address:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :groups, though: addresses
end

# This is not tested, just illustrating the idea.
```

It is also possible that the the relationship, between groups, providers and addresses is dependent on the ids for two of the three embedded?, in this case I'd like to know more for the reasoning behind this design.

Comment: The relationship between provider and group is dependant on the 'groups address'  Normally a provider would be long to a group, but i needed it more granular as a group can have many locations.  So in this case a provider does belong a group but through the groups locations.  The reason is that a group might or might not have more than one location.  A provider might or might not belong to more than one group. But a provider will belong to a group, and if it does it will be at a specific location, but it could belong to the group in many locations.  Regardless it is still part of that group.

Comment: In the case, it seems to me that the provider address "has_one" provider(i know it sounds funky). because if a provider will always belong to a group at a specific location. 

Q1: does the provider has many or just one group?
Q2: what do you mean with could belong to "a group in many locations"? that it can belong to a group with many locations or that it can belong to many groups based on diferent locations?

Comment: So the provider_location should have a has_one even though I already say belongs_to?  and yes a provider can belong to many groups.  But the granularity is many groups through a location. I.e. a provider can belong to group A but its at group a's location 1 , 2 and 5.   Same a provider can also belong to Group B at group b's location 2.  etc...  Also adding that has_one provider in the provider_address gives me an error about can't write unknown attribute 'provider_location_id' so I am thinking id need a migration to support that?  I can post my schema as it is now if that helps as well?